# how to add 2d text over my 3d object created through blender

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, babylonjs

i have a 3d model created with blender and i want to place 2d text over the various meshes of the imported model. i am successfull in changing colors of the meshes on the basis of their indices by diffuse.color but unable to drawtext over my mesh.

> code used to change color:

```js
scene.meshes[indexValue].material.diffuseColor = color;
   allMeshChange =indexValue == scene.meshes.length - 1;
```

> and for text i am doing this:

```js
 var impact =  var impact =scene.meshes[1];
    impact.material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("impactMat", scene);
     impact.material.emissiveColor = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 0.5);
   impact.position = new BABYLON.Vector3(scene.meshes[1].position);
   var backgroundTexture = new BABYLON.DynamicTexture("dynamic texture", 512, scene, true);
impact.material.diffuseTexture = backgroundTexture;

impact.material.specularColor = new BABYLON.Color3(1, 1, 1);
impact.material.backFaceCulling = false;

backgroundTexture.drawText("test", null, 80, "italic 80px Segoe UI", "white", "#555555");
```

i am new to babylon js . Kindly help in writing text over mesh.

Answer (score 1):

What is the `options` argument meaning with the current value `512` on the `BABYLON.DynamicTexture` constructor ? Cause to determine the 2d context for printing the text it's looking for a `getContext(:string)` method. Instead, you should pass it your canvas known as a HTMLCanvasElement.